# Is excessive saliva production during pregnancy normal?

Tags: health, pregnancy, mother

I am 10 weeks pregnant now and getting excessive saliva. Does that mean something and will it stop some time soon? Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: As someone who has been there, don't worry about every little symptom and sign during pregnancy.  Keep a list of anything you need to ask your practitioner at your monthly visits (assuming they do those wherever you are) and once an item is on the list, forget about it unless it's serious.  In that case call your doctor immediately.  Otherwise you'll fret your pregnancy away and 40 weeks is a long time to fret.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention, but I bet when this was happening you were also experiencing some morning sickness.  When your body feels like it's going to vomit, saliva production increases to help protect your upper GI tract from the acid.

In late pregnancy when acid reflux can be a problem, you can also get a lot of saliva or mucus as a reaction to the irritation of your mouth and sinuses.

Answer (score -1):

I had excessive saliva in my 2nd pregnancy it was like a nightmare, the whole day i cant swallow my saliva ,.that was my biggest problem ..my Doctor told me that may be it will continue with me the whole pregnancy!!  but don’t worry honey it gone at 20 week completely .. but you have to try everything that make it easier..listen to these tips , you can spend all day with eating nuts ..even when you are outside .. I’m used to put it in my car and like the sunflower seeds in  my bag every time .. the salty one . It was really useful , which is let your mouth dry .. 
be strong don’t give up .. its hard but it will go anyways . I had a worst time with this experience but once it gone.. everything will be fine